# Using GPU on Apple M1 with TensorFlow and BERT

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, apple-m1, bert-language-model

I'm currently trying to build a text classifier with BERT in TensorFlow on my M1 Mac. I followed the advice [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/721619?page=2) to install all necessary packages, opting for tf and tf-text 2.9.0, and tf-metal 0.5.0

My model looks as follows:

```
text_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name = "text") 
encoder_inputs = bert_preprocess(text_input) 
encoder_outputs = bert_encoder(encoder_inputs) 
bert_embeds = encoder_outputs["pooled_output"] 
intermediate_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation = "relu", name = "intermediate_layer")(bert_embeds) 
dropout_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1, name = "dropout_layer")(intermediate_layer) 
output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = "sigmoid", name = "output_layer")(dropout_layer) 
model = tf.keras.Model(text_input, output_layer)
```

However, I'm getting the following error when fitting the model:

```
2 root error(s) found. (0) NOT_FOUND: No registered 'AddN' OpKernel for 'GPU' devices compatible with node {{node model_13/keras_layer_1/StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall/bert_pack_inputs/PartitionedCall/RaggedConcat/ArithmeticOptimizer/AddOpsRewrite_Leaf_0_add_2}} (OpKernel was found, but attributes didn't match) Requested Attributes: N=2, T=DT_INT64, _XlaHasReferenceVars=false, _grappler_ArithmeticOptimizer_AddOpsRewriteStage=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0" . Registered: device='XLA_CPU_JIT'; T in [DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE, DT_INT32, DT_UINT8, DT_INT16, 16534343205130372495, DT_COMPLEX128, DT_HALF, DT_UINT32, DT_UINT64, DT_VARIANT] device='GPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT] device='DEFAULT'; T in [DT_INT32] device='CPU'; T in [DT_UINT64] device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT64] device='CPU'; T in [DT_UINT32] device='CPU'; T in [DT_UINT16] device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT16] device='CPU'; T in [DT_UINT8] device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT8] device='CPU'; T in [DT_INT32] device='CPU'; T in [DT_HALF] device='CPU'; T in [DT_BFLOAT16] device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT] device='CPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE] device='CPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX64] device='CPU'; T in [DT_COMPLEX128] device='CPU'; T in [DT_VARIANT]
```

I found a similar question/discussion [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/711402?login=true&page=1#760713022), but no satisfying solution was proposed.

Do I interpret the error code correctly, that only int64 is supported currently by the AddN Op Kernel? However, this would conflict with the bert_embeds pooled_output which is in float32 (I tried forcing to float64, but that didn't solve the issue). My outcome variable is binary, I forced it to int64.

My model works when I run it on CPU, but is just quite slow. Any help on how to make the model run my GPU would be appreciated.

Thanks!